# How to get the TTL of incoming UDP packets on Windows?

Tags: windows, go, udp, ttl

I'm want to get the TTL of incoming UDP packages in Go on Windows. It's an easy task in linux using ReadMsgUDP() but I can't do it on Windows. I think that the package x/ipv4 it's not properly documented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting incoming TTL in GO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109485/getting-incoming-ttl-in-go)

Comment: No, this answer works perfectly on Linux but not on Windows. Thanks!